# Python encoding format

Tags: python, format, decode, encode

I have the need to store python `str` in a database to retrieve it and then apply a `format()` and `encode()` methods on it in order to shape my request frame an convert it into `bytes` and finally `send()` it through a `socket`.

MWE is like this:

```
fstr = '{slaveid:}{command:s}\x0d'
cstr = fstr.format(slaveid=chr(128+43), command='flags')
bstr = cstr.encode()
```

And produce the following output:

```
{slaveid:}{command:s}
«flags
b'\xc2\xabflags\r'
```

My problem occurs at the third line, char greater than 127 become two bytes when performing `encode()` method. Is suppose it is all about charset definition and because default encoding `'ascii'` is limited to 127.

How should I define my encoding in order to get the following conversion:

```
b'\xabflags\r'
```

I am a little lost in front of [charset tables](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Comment: Are you trying to create a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) ? You can try: `bytearray(cstr)`

Comment: you can use `cstr.encode('latin-1')`

Comment: *"char greater than 127 become two bytes when performing encode() method. Is suppose it is all about charset definition"* - That's because `encode()` is encoding the string as UTF-8 and `\xc2\xab` is the UTF-8 encoding for `\u00ab` (the `«` character). You could try `cstr.encode(encoding='iso-8859-1')` instead.

Comment: @Saksow: I know about bytearray but it not necessary here I think. I prefer control encoding when performing encode(). Thank you for answering

Comment: @MukundMK, Gord Thompson, I found 'cp1252' to work also. 'latin-1' and 'iso-8859-1' work too. Does one of you mind about writing an anwser that I accept, stating what is a best choice for encoding among those possibilities and if char between 128 and 255 are the same within each charset. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to the question, the issue is a result of the `.encode()` method encoding the string to UTF-8 by default. The character inserted by `chr(128+43)` is `\u00ab` which is encoded to two bytes in UTF-8: `\xc2\xab`.

The solution is to specify a single-byte character encoding when calling `.encode()`. Any of the following will work ...

```python
cstr.encode(encoding='latin_1')
cstr.encode(encoding='iso-8859-1')
cstr.encode(encoding='cp1252')
```

... although it should be noted that while `iso-8859-1` is just an alias for `latin_1`, `cp1252` and `latin_1` are *not* the same thing. However, in your case it shouldn't matter because the actual "character" is not important, just its (single) byte value in `range(256)`.